# Issue in the update step of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently trying to implement Conway's Game of Life in Java. On a first glance the application seems to work as it either stalls in the states that are expected as stalling states (e.g. block, bee-hive and tub) or changes infinitely.

However, as I took a closer look I never actually saw a Blinker or Beacon nor a Loaf (for reference images of these states see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns)). So I decided to implement a drawing mode and a one-step-update method that gives me the possibility to analyze exactly what's going on.

The strange thing that I found was the following:
When entering Drawing Mode I reset all cells and all buffered cells on the board to dead. Then, I drew a vertical Blinker somewhere in the middle of the board and did one update step and checked for the update mechanism of all cells that are alive (which are only the 3 cells belonging to the Blinker). In the output however, all of them returned that the value to their bottom left was alive (which actually could not be the case because nothing is being logged for these cells).

I'm really confused about where I went wrong in my code because this just doesn't make any sense for me. The values for the next generation are being stored in a buffer and only written back after the next generation has been calculated entirely, so I don't think that this should be the issue.

For reproducibility, here is the code:

Main.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowUI();
        });
        
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        
        AnimationPanel panel = new AnimationPanel();
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game of Life");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyReleased(e);
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_R) {
                    panel.reset();
                    panel.startAnimation();
                }
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_C) {
                    panel.clear();
                }
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S) {
                    panel.startAnimation();
                }
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_SPACE) {
                    panel.stepAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        panel.populate();
        panel.startAnimation();
        
    }
    
}
```

AnimationPanel.java:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimationPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4929258196354814855L;
    private int width = 1920;
    private int height = 1080;
    private int gridSize = 10;
    private Cell[][] cells;
    private Cell[][] buffer;
    private Timer timer;
    
    private boolean drawingMode = false;
    
    public AnimationPanel() {
        
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                
                if(drawingMode) {
                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();
                    
                    int xIndex = (int)x / gridSize;
                    int yIndex = (int)y / gridSize;
                    
                    cells[xIndex][yIndex].live = !cells[xIndex][yIndex].live;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            
        });
        
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        timer.stop();
        cells = null;
        buffer = null;
        populate();
    }
    
    public void clear() {
        timer.stop();
        
        for(Cell[] row : cells) {
            for(Cell cell: row) {
                cell.live = false;
            }
        }
        
        for(Cell[] row : buffer) {
            for(Cell cell: row) {
                cell.live = false;
            }
        }
        
        repaint();
        
        drawingMode = true;
        
    }
    
    public void populate() {
        
        Random random = new Random();
        
        int horizontalCellCount = width / gridSize;
        int verticalCellCount = height / gridSize;
        
        cells = new Cell[horizontalCellCount][verticalCellCount];
        buffer = new Cell[horizontalCellCount][verticalCellCount];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < horizontalCellCount; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < verticalCellCount; j++) {
                double randVal = random.nextDouble();
                
                boolean live = (randVal < 0.05) ? true : false;
                
                int x = i * gridSize;
                int y = j * gridSize;
                cells[i][j] = new Cell(live, x, y, gridSize);
                buffer[i][j] = new Cell(live, x, y, gridSize);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        for(Cell[] row : cells) {
            for(Cell cell : row) {
                cell.draw(g);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
    
    public void startAnimation() {
        drawingMode = false;
        timer = new Timer(250, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void stepAnimation() {
        update();
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
        repaint();
    }
    
    private void update() {
        int horizontalCellCount = width / gridSize;
        int verticalCellCount = height / gridSize;
        
        boolean log = false;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < horizontalCellCount; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < verticalCellCount; j++) {
                
                if(cells[i][j].live) {
                    log = true;
                    System.out.println("Cell: (" + i + "|" + j + ") " + cells[i][j].toString());
                    System.out.println("Row length: " + cells[i].length);
                    System.out.println("Column length: " + cells.length);
                } else {
                    log = false;
                }
                
                int liveNeighours = 0;
                
                for(int x = i - 1; x <= i + 1; x++) {
                    
                    if(x < 0 || x == horizontalCellCount) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    for(int y = j - 1; y <= j + 1; y++) {
                        
                        if(y < 0 || y == verticalCellCount || y == j && x == i) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        if(cells[x][y].live) {
                            liveNeighours++;
                        }
                        
                        if(log) {
                            System.out.println("Cell at " + x + "|" + y + ": " + cells[x][y].live + " - liveNeighbours: " + liveNeighours);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Cell cell = cells[i][j];
                
                if(liveNeighours > 3 || liveNeighours < 2) {
                    buffer[i][j].live = false;
                } else if(!cell.live && liveNeighours == 3) {
                    buffer[i][j].live = true;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < horizontalCellCount; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < verticalCellCount; j++) {
                cells[i][j] = buffer[i][j];
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Cell.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Cell {
    
    public boolean live;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int size;
    
    public Cell(boolean live, int x, int y, int size) {
        
        this.live = live;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if(live) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + " " + y + ") - Size: " + size;
    }
    
}
```

Any help is really appreciated on this as I'm really confused what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I can’t see the problem that you’re describing offhand, but you do have a mistake with calculation of `liveNeighbours` - that value should NOT include the cell itself - so `if(cells[x][y].live &&  x != i && y != j) { liveNeighbours++;}`
                            liveNeighours++;

Comment: @racraman I think you overlooked this part of the code: I included this check when looping over y where I skip the iteration if `x == i && y == j` (right above the if statement you mentioned).

Comment: Oops, I did too - I shouldn’t try debugging on a phone !

Comment: It looks like you don't update `buffer` for the case where it should be the same as whatever's in the cell.  In other words, it looks like there should be a final `else buffer[i][j].live = cells[i][j].live` in the update logic. fwiw, here's another implementation that uses simpler data structures to reduce copying and other kinds of overhead: https://gist.github.com/gene-ressler/99c4a8ca13fa07b5eea6

Comment: @Gene I think you refer to the case where a cell lives on from one generation to the next, right? If this is the case, then I think that line should be redundant, because `buffer` should have the same cell values as `cells` at the start, and thus updating only the cells that change should be sufficient (because why would I want to update something that doesn't change?). Or do you mean something else here that I'm missing?

Comment: Still on my phone ! :D.   When updating the cells in the final `for` loop, try changing `cells[i][j] = buffer[i][j];` to `cells[i][j].live = buffer[i][j].live;`.  The way it is at the moment, you are making both the’`cells` and the `buffer` the same instances, so the second time you call `update` and set `buffer[i][j].live = true;`, you are not only setting the `buffer` but the `cell` as well, which will be used in the next iteration of x,y,I,j

Comment: @racraman Thanks, that really solved the issue. Now I just need to clean things up for the drawing mode but I guess that should be less of an issue now

Comment: I think you forgot to set buffer = true for the living cells with 2 or 3 neighbours